# using Coderay with a html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coderay

Has anyone got any experience with using Coderay with html.erb files. I'm unsure how to use coderay with these files.

I have a helper method

```
def coderay(text)
  text.gsub(/\<code( lang="(.+?)")?\>(.+?)\<\/code\>/m) do
    CodeRay.scan($3, $2).div(:css => :class)
  end
end
```

I save all my text into my model and encapsulate anything i want formatted using coderay like so

```
<code lang="ruby">
  <div class="sidebarbox-title">
    <h3>Posts</h3>
  </div>
  <% @posts.each do |p| %>
    <h3 class="post-header">
      <%= p.name %>
    </h3>
   <% end %>
</code>
```

when i want to use coderay formatted text in my view i then do

```
<%= coderay(@post.comments).html_safe %>
```

How do i specify what the language is though if using .html.erb, so to clarify

```
<code lang="**What goes here**">
  <div class="sidebarbox-title">
    <h3>Posts</h3>
  </div>
  <% @posts.each do |p| %>
    <h3 class="post-header">
      <%= p.name %>
    </h3>
   <% end %>
</code>
```

The docs [Here](http://coderay.rubychan.de/doc/CodeRay/Scanners/ERB.html) seem to state that it can be done, but cant see how

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain this "How do i specify what the language is though if using .html.erb"?

Comment: @pavan if I'm using ruby code lang=ruby, if I'm using html code, lang=html, if I'm using html.erb what do i pass as the lang ?

Answer (score 1):

And the answer was stupidly obvious

```
 <code lang="erb">
  <div class="sidebarbox-title">
    <h3>Posts</h3>
  </div>
    <% @posts.each do |p| %>
      <h3 class="post-header">
        <%= p.name %>
      </h3>
   <% end %>
 </code>
```